# Domain model of Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, domain-model, tfs-sdk

Did anybody see a domain model (information model) of Microsoft TFS (team foundation server)? Where it can be found? I need to understand ability to integrate it with other product.

Comment: What version of tfs are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the Domain Model (which is definitely not public), but the TFS Integration Platform may be helpful:
http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Woodward](http://www.woodwardweb.com/)'s blog is extremely TFS-centric. Try looking there.

Also, try [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130307.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the [Team Foundation Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) which I think is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official TFS SDK documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx

When you [install it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b&displaylang=en), you'll get lots more sample code that isn't posted online.

[Links to links](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/08/12/tfs_api_links.aspx) courtesy of Buck Hodges.

Once you decide which pieces of TFS you're interested in, you can search the web for additional examples based on the root class.  For instance, if you want to write a Version Control plugin, you might type "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client site:blogs.msdn.com" into your favorite search engine.